# how to use allow origin regex pattern in jupyter lab config

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Hi I am trying to configure jupyter lab to only allow access from certain IPs. I know that I can set
`c.ServerApp.allow_origin = '*'` in the config file at `~/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py` but I worry that this is to broad.

The [docs](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other/full-config.html) mention the option `ServerApp.allow_origin_pat` which accepts a regex to allow only matching origins. Unfortunately they dont mention what regex syntax they are using. If for example I want to restrict access to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.39.*` I would use the following regex with the python syntax: `192\.39\.\d+\.\d+|localhost|127\.0\.0\.1`. However when starting jupyter lab will complain as follows:

```
[E 2022-08-24 11:09:54.311 LabApp] Exception while loading config file /home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/optuna_raytune/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 738,
 in _load_config_files
        config = loader.load_config()
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/optuna_raytune/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/loader.py", line 614, in l
oad_config
        self._read_file_as_dict()
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/optuna_raytune/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/loader.py", line 646, in _
read_file_as_dict
        exec(compile(f.read(), conf_filename, 'exec'), namespace, namespace)
      File "/home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py", line 605
        1xtra arguments that will be passed to Jinja environment.
         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So my question is, how do I construct a correct regex?

Comment: error shows problem in line `605` in file `/home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py` and you should check what is in this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is "1xtra" on line 605 in file "/home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py".  You need to comment that line out (and optionally correct the miss-spelling).  Also, be aware that all of the 127/8 block is localhost.

Comment: ah right I had another typo in my config which was unrelated to the regex... Thanks for spotting that